# need help making website responsive #2

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

everyone! I'm currently doing some free work for a friend of mine to contribute to my portfolio and keep me on my feet learning.

Everything is going great and looking great, but unfortunately, I'm having a lot of trouble trying to make some of the content responsive. I'm using the Bootstrap grid framework.

Alright so here's my CSS

```css
.footertext {
  font-family: 'Oxygen', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: white;
  margin-left: 30px;
  opacity: 0.5;
  text-align: right;
}
.lastbox {
  font-family: 'Oxygen', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 19px;
  text-align: center;
}
.footer {
  background-size: cover;
  height: 105px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1000px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  margin-top: 100px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;

}
.boxmain {
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 25em;
  background-size: cover;
  max-width: 100%;

}
.videocenter {
  text-align: center;
}
.video {
  padding-top: 1.875em;
  text-align: center;
}
.underh {
  font-family: 'Oxygen', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 22px;
  padding-top: 2.0625em;
  margin-left: 1.25em;
  max-width: 100%;
}
.heading {
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 49px;
}
.box1 {
  padding-top: 25px;
}
body {
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  background: url(background.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1000px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
  max-width: 100%;

}
.logo {
  display: block;
  width: 75%;
  height: 96%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}

/*-------------------------------------------------------*/
/* NAVBAR
/*-------------------------------------------------------*/

.navbar {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  border: none;
  min-height: 60px;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  z-index: 1200;
}

.navbar-nav {
  margin: 0;
  float: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

.navbar-nav > li > a {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 0 24px;
  line-height: 90px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 19px;
  font-weight: 300;
  letter-spacing: 0.02em;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.navigation-overlay {
  background-color: rgba(17, 17, 17, 0.5);
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.navigation-overlay.sticky {
  background: #000;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 0.75;
}

.navigation-overlay.sticky .navbar-nav > li > a,
.navigation-overlay.sticky .menu-socials li > a {
  line-height: 60px;
}

.navbar-header {
  width: 20%;
  padding-right: 15px;
}

.nav-wrap {
  width: 60%;
}

.menu-socials {
  width: 20%;
  float: right;
  padding: 0 15px;
}

.logo-container {
  padding: 0 15px;
  float: left;
}

.logo-wrap {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.logo-wrap > a {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 90px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.logo-wrap.shrink > a {
  height: 60px;
}

.logo-wrap img {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  height: 66px;
}

.logo-wrap.shrink img {
  height: 48px;
}

.navbar-collapse.in {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-nav > .active > a,
.navbar-nav > .active > a:focus,
.navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
.menu-socials li > a:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.navbar-collapse {
  padding: 0;
  border-top: none;
}

.nav .open > a,
.nav .open > a:focus,
.nav .open > a:hover,
.nav > li > a:focus,
.nav > li > a:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-color: #f2f2f2;
}

@media (max-width: 991px) {
  .navigation-overlay,
  .navigation-overlay.sticky {
    background-color: rgba(17, 17, 17, 0.9);
  }
  .nav-wrap {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    min-height: 0;
  }
  .nav-type-1 .container-fluid {
    padding: 0 15px;
  }
  .navbar-header {
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: 0;
  }
  .logo-wrap img {
    height: 48px;
  }
  .logo-wrap > a {
    height: 60px;
  }
  .navbar-nav {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 40px 0;
  }
  .navigation-overlay.sticky .navbar-nav > li > a,
  .navigation-overlay .navbar-nav > li > a {
    padding: 10px 0;
    line-height: 30px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="navigation-overlay sticky">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <!-- Logo -->
        <div class="logo-container">
          <div class="logo-wrap local-scroll shrink">
            <a href="#home">
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-12 nav-wrap">
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse text-center" id="navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav local-scroll text-center">
            <li class="active">
              <a href="#home">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#services">Team</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#portfolio">Works</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#about-us">Events</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- end col -->
    </div>
    <!-- end row -->
  </div>
  <!-- end container -->
</div>
<!-- end navigation -->
<img class="logo img-fluid" alt="Eye Of The Storm"src="logo.png">
<div class="boxmain">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <div class="video">
        </div>
        <iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/video.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Feyeofthestormpro%2Fvideos%2F638067739703491%2F&show_text=0&width=560" width="560" height="315" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" allowFullScreen="true"></iframe>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <p class="underh">Eye of the Storm Productions is an entertainment business dedicated to its involvement in the electronic music scene.
          We offer a large range of services to  the underground electronic music scene and pride ourselves on the work that we do.
          We offer our own selection of the best aspiring young DJs/Producers and photographers/cinematographers, as well as professionally run stage management solutions.
          We have also partnered with Fulcrum Designs and Staging, to bring you the best in stage design and construction.  Including custom shade sail installation and VJ services.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="footer">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Feyeofthestormpro&width=450&layout=standard&action=like&size=small&show_faces=true&share=true&height=80&appId" width="450" height="80" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <p class="footertext">Copyright © 2017 Eye Of The Storm Productions. All Rights Reserved.</p>
        <p class="footertext">Website developed by Charlie Fisher</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm focousing more on trying to make the middle white backround and content inside responsive thank you!

Comment: Validate your markup before anything please, you have multiple errors.

Comment: Done! Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: Hey um, why is it two code snippets, combine your css with the html

Answer (score 1):

Try this. It'll improve the page responsiveness :

```css
body{
  width:100%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  max-width:100%;
}
.container-fluid,.row{
  width:100%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  max-width:100%;
}
.footertext {
  font-family: 'Oxygen', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: white;
  margin-left: 30px;
  opacity: 0.5;
  text-align: right;
}
.lastbox {
  font-family: 'Oxygen', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 19px;
  text-align: center;
}
.footer {
  background-size: cover;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1000px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  padding:20px 0 10px 0;
}
.boxmain {
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
  min-height:32.7em;
  background-size: cover;
  max-width: 100%;
}
.videocenter {
  text-align: center;
}
.video {
  padding-top: 1.875em;
  text-align: center;
}
.underh {
  font-family: 'Oxygen', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 22px;
  padding-top: 2.0625em;
  margin-left: 1.25em;
  max-width: 100%;
}
.heading {
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 49px;
}
.box1 {
  padding-top: 25px;
}
body {
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  background: url(background.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1000px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
  max-width: 100%;

}
.logo {
  display: block;
  width: 75%;
  height: 96%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}

/*-------------------------------------------------------*/
/* NAVBAR
/*-------------------------------------------------------*/

.navbar {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  border: none;
  min-height: 60px;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  z-index: 1200;
}

.navbar-nav {
  margin: 0;
  float: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

.navbar-nav > li > a {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 0 24px;
  line-height: 90px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 19px;
  font-weight: 300;
  letter-spacing: 0.02em;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.navigation-overlay {
  background-color: rgba(17, 17, 17, 0.5);
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.navigation-overlay.sticky {
  background: #000;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 0.75;
}

.navigation-overlay.sticky .navbar-nav > li > a,
.navigation-overlay.sticky .menu-socials li > a {
  line-height: 60px;
}

.navbar-header {
  width: 20%;
  padding-right: 15px;
}

.nav-wrap {
  width: 60%;
}

.menu-socials {
  width: 20%;
  float: right;
  padding: 0 15px;
}

.logo-container {
  padding: 0 15px;
  float: left;
}

.logo-wrap {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.logo-wrap > a {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 90px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.logo-wrap.shrink > a {
  height: 60px;
}

.logo-wrap img {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  height: 66px;
}

.logo-wrap.shrink img {
  height: 48px;
}

.navbar-collapse.in {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-nav > .active > a,
.navbar-nav > .active > a:focus,
.navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
.menu-socials li > a:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.navbar-collapse {
  padding: 0;
  border-top: none;
}

.nav .open > a,
.nav .open > a:focus,
.nav .open > a:hover,
.nav > li > a:focus,
.nav > li > a:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-color: #f2f2f2;
}

@media (max-width: 991px) {
  .navigation-overlay,
  .navigation-overlay.sticky {
    background-color: rgba(17, 17, 17, 0.9);
  }
  .nav-wrap {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    min-height: 0;
  }
  .nav-type-1 .container-fluid {
    padding: 0 15px;
  }
  .navbar-header {
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: 0;
  }
  .logo-wrap img {
    height: 48px;
  }
  .logo-wrap > a {
    height: 60px;
  }
  .navbar-nav {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 40px 0;
  }
  .navigation-overlay.sticky .navbar-nav > li > a,
  .navigation-overlay .navbar-nav > li > a {
    padding: 10px 0;
    line-height: 30px;
  }
}

div.video{
  width:80%;
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <div class="navigation-overlay sticky">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <!-- Logo -->
          <div class="logo-container">
            <div class="logo-wrap local-scroll shrink">
              <a href="#home">
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-12 nav-wrap">
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse text-center" id="navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav local-scroll text-center">
              <li class="active">
                <a href="#home">Home</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#services">Team</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#portfolio">Works</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#about-us">Events</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- end col -->
      </div>
      <!-- end row -->
    </div>
    <!-- end container -->
  </div>
  <!-- end navigation -->
  <img class="logo img-fluid" alt="Eye Of The Storm"src="logo.png">
  <div class="boxmain">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
          <div class="video">
            <iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/video.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Feyeofthestormpro%2Fvideos%2F638067739703491%2F&show_text=0&width=560" width="560" height="315" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" allowFullScreen="true"></iframe>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
          <p class="underh">Eye of the Storm Productions is an entertainment business dedicated to its involvement in the electronic music scene.
            We offer a large range of services to  the underground electronic music scene and pride ourselves on the work that we do.
            We offer our own selection of the best aspiring young DJs/Producers and photographers/cinematographers, as well as professionally run stage management solutions.
            We have also partnered with Fulcrum Designs and Staging, to bring you the best in stage design and construction.  Including custom shade sail installation and VJ services.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="footer">
      <div class="row" class="footerRow">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
          <iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Feyeofthestormpro&width=450&layout=standard&action=like&size=small&show_faces=true&share=true&height=80&appId" width="450" height="80" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
          <p class="footertext">Copyright © 2017 Eye Of The Storm Productions. All Rights Reserved.</p>
          <p class="footertext">Website developed by Charlie Fisher</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Also for responsive navigation refer to [bootstrap-navbar template](https://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-default).If you scroll down t=on this page , there is pre-written code for responsive navigation.