# making website completely mobile friendly

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, mobile

I have posted previous threads on how to make my website more responsive all have which helped me a lot. Unfortunately though when the website is viewed on a mobile device, everything is layered over each other, and the text does not resize or the videos. Here's my previous thread.

[need help making website responsive #2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41254343/need-help-making-website-responsive-2/41255437#41255437)

I would like to know how to make elements invisible and visible when viewed on different mobile devices such as tablets and phones. So I can have a different layout that is more mobile friendly.

Can someone point me in the right direction or tell me what tag would be appropriate? Also I'm using the bootstrap framework.

Comment: https://www.uxpin.com/studio/blog/a-hands-on-guide-to-mobile-first-design/

Comment: look into CSS media queries

Comment: I have VicDid, but I can't find what I'm looking for unfortunately :(

Answer (score 1):

Use media queries to target the various screen sizes and use CSS to define the properties of the elements when resized as shown below:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
    div {
        float: left;
        background: red;
    }
    .......
}
```

You can refer to this article for more information
https://www.toptal.com/designers/responsive/introduction-to-responsive-web-design-pseudo-elements-media-queries